# UpdateReportedPropertiesAsync with complex types?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to update some Azure IoT Device Twin properties like this:

```
static async void MainAsync()
{
    DeviceClient deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

    TwinCollection reportedProperties = new TwinCollection();


    dynamic heatingModes = new[]
    {
        new { Id="OUT2", Name="Comfort" },
        new { Id="OUT", Name="Away" },
    };

    reportedProperties["heatingMode"] = "AWAY";
    reportedProperties["supportedHeatingModes"] = heatingModes;

    await deviceClient.UpdateReportedPropertiesAsync(reportedProperties);
}
```

The above code does not work and none of the Device Twin properties are not updated.

If I comment out this line everything works fine and the heatingMode property is updated as expected:

```
reportedProperties["supportedHeatingModes"] = heatingModes;
```

I have also tried to use a regular (not dynamic) type for heatingModes, but it does not work either.

I also tried to manually serialize the object to JSON:

```
reportedProperties["supportedHeatingModes"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(heatingModes);
```

But, the resulting JSON was kind of ugly with escaped quotes:

[image: Device Twin properties]

Why doesn't the updating the supportedHeatingModes property work for objects based on complex types?

Any other workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the MSDN document [Understand and use device twins in IOT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins#tags-and-properties-format) , where is described:

*All values in JSON objects can be of the following JSON types: boolean, number, string, object. **Arrays are not allowed**.*